# Rails Associations Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, associations

Not much of a rails/ruby programming question and more of a resource question. Is there any site or resource that fields scenarios and it's up to you to figure out how to model the tables and models and what association to use, where to put the foreign key with an answer key that tells you why you should use X or Y?

Something like that seems like it would be more powerful of a study/learning tool than simply having people just type code verbatim. Does any such resource exist?

Comment: yeah, its all over on the internet, just read database management basics and code and see lots of open source codes, follow the railscast.com

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html maybe this may help you.

Comment: @argentum47 do you have any recommendations on some github repositories worth looking into by chance?

Comment: spot-us , loved-by-less, rails-admin and some gems that were made by ryan-bates and radar should be a start.. btw, the first two are rails 3 I think